# How do I change the Django login to allow for emails as well?

Tags: python, django, url, authentication

Currently, this is how I do my login:

```
(r'^login/?$','django.contrib.auth.views.login',{'template_name':'login.html'}),
```

I'm using Django's built in contrib.

What do I have to do so that people can type in their **email or their username** to login?

Comment: Someone told me about a site called Google . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a custom authentication backend, like this:

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1001/